# How can I get a list of the positions of the running minima in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want the positions of the (sequential) running minima in a list, that is, the positions of entries that have the minimum value of all the elements in that list, up to and including that entry.  For instance, given the list `{3,4,4,2,5,5,1}`, the output should be `{1,4,7}`.

Comment: Flatten@Position[list, x_ /; x < 4]?

Comment: What does "new minimum" mean?  You probably need `Split`.

Comment: This question feels familiar; if anyone recalls something similar please link it in these comments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, I think I had an answer for something similar, will go through my ans. and check...

Comment: Related: [(1754)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1754/121), [(38325)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38325/121).  Somewhat related: [(30438)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30438/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lst = {3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1};
```

Assuming by "new minimum" you mean "running minima", you can use

```
Accumulate@Most@Join[{1}, Length /@ Split[FoldList[Min, First@lst, Rest@lst]]]
(* {1, 4, 7}  *)
```

We get the same results with:

```
Accumulate@Most@Join[{1}, Length /@ Split[FoldList[Min, lst]]] (* thanks: Mr. Wizard *)
```

and

```
ReplacePart[#, p : _ :> If[p == 1 || #[[p]] < Min[#[[;; p - 1]]], p, ## &[]]] &[lst]
```

Comment: At least the first of these answers is incorrect.  For input `lst = {3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 2}`, the output is `{1, 4, 7, 10}` but note that the final `2` in `lst` is not a true running minimum (there is a lower `1` earlier in `lst`) and hence there should be no position `10` in the output.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG.Stork. You are right; only the last one gives the sequential minima (I hope :)). I will delete the first four.

Comment: There is [no need for `First@` and `Last@` in `FoldList`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121).

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. The two-argument form also works in version 9.0.1.0  despite the syntax highlighting that suggest  missing argument.

Comment: @kguler My self-answer to the linked question above explains how to resolve that. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Despite there already being an accepted answer, my entry:

Update: Something else I came up with, cleaner and generally faster by a goodly margin than below and *much* faster in my tests against other answers I tested:

```
f3 = Module[{mp = First@Pick[Range@Length@#, 
                             If[VectorQ[#, IntegerQ], Subtract[#, Min@#], 
                                Unitize@Subtract[#, Min@#]], 0] &, lst = #},
    NestWhileList[mp[lst[[;; # - 1]]] &, mp[lst], # != 1 &][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]] &;
```

I'll leave the earlier attempts for reference.

```
f = Module[{lst = #,nextpos = 1,
            minpos = First@Pick[Range@Length@#, 
                                If[VectorQ[#, IntegerQ], Subtract[#, Min@#], 
                                             Unitize@Subtract[#, Min@#]], 0],
            rec = First@# + 1, min, v1, v2},

    min = lst[[minpos]];

    {v1, v2} = 
     Reap@NestWhileList[lst[[Sow[ nextpos = First@Pick[Range[nextpos, minpos], 
                                UnitStep@Subtract[lst[[nextpos ;; minpos]], #], 0]]]] &, 
                        rec, # != min &];

    {Rest@v1, First@v2}] &;

f[{20,30,50,4,5,6,8,2,3,1,0,4}]

(* {{20, 4, 2, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 8, 10, 11}} *)
```

Returns record values and positions.

Should be order+ magnitude faster on integer lists with duplication, competitive on sparse and/or non-integer ones.

The same short-circuiting can be used to dramatically improve the performance of *kguler*'s answer by simply adding the restriction:

```
Accumulate@
 Most@Join[{1}, Length /@ Split[FoldList[Min, First@lst, 
                                Rest@(lst[[;; First@Pick[Range@Length@lst, 
                                          If[VectorQ[#, IntegerQ], Subtract[lst, Min@lst], 
                                             Unitize@Subtract[lst, Min@lst]], 0]]])]]]
```

N.b. - when I checked, a few of the earlier answers appear to return incorrect results...

Comment: `f3` tests slow for me.  I am using:  `SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[9999999, 500000];
list -= Accumulate@RandomInteger[1, 500000];`

Comment: Hm... wait, now your older `f` also seems slower even after a restart.  Would you test my new method please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sure, give me a few minutes. Just did quick bmark against accepted on 1M integer lists with 1k,10k,100k,1M distincts, was 16-40X faster. Testing yours now...

Comment: I swear yours was testing faster for me ten minutes ago but now it seems slower; I guess I changed `list` but I cannot remember how.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Well, monitoring so far, yours faster than *kguler*'s, but f3 is smoking it... I'm using RandomInteger[{0, z}, 1000000] with z {1000,10000,100000,1000000} (on netbook, so no really huge lists)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Here's averages over 20 runs each for the above, *kguler*'s, mine, your integer-specific faster update:
{{0.516363, 0.017940, 0.407943}, {0.773765, 0.021060, 
  0.710585}, {0.762065, 0.0257402, 0.684844}, {0.740225, 0.052260, 
  0.655984}}

Comment: Ah, I see now.  `RandomInteger` results in few minimums existing.  I added `ist -= Accumulate . . .` to create more, but now I see that this is avoiding exactly the case your method is optimized for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes. If the lists are structured specifically in the form you make, there are more efficient methods (like yours, pretty BTW, and +1 inbound), but those methods suffer over other cases...

Answer (score 4):

Update: here is a more efficient method also using `Min` and `FoldList` (from kguler) but with my own style.  It is significantly faster than his code and far more efficient that my earlier attempts below.

If the input list has a decreasing trend this method is the fastest yet posted.  However if the data is uniformly distributed rasher's optimization will on average be considerably faster.

```
list = {3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 2};

SparseArray[Differences@# ~Prepend~ 1]["AdjacencyLists"] & @ FoldList[Min, list]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 7}
> ```

---

Not highly efficient but rather direct:

```
list = {3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 6, 9, 2};

f[{min_, pos_}, new_] :=
 {If[new < min, Sow[pos]; new, min], pos + 1}

Reap[Fold[f, {∞, 1}, list]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 7}
> ```

An adaptation of Simon's method from [How to pick increasing numbers from the list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/how-to-pick-increasing-numbers-from-the-list/38329#38329):

```
Module[{i = ∞}, 
 Join @@ Position[list, x_ /; x < i && (i = x; True), Heads -> False]
]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 7}
> ```

Comment: Just a note - sparse solutions fail if lists are non-decreasing, returning {} instead of first ele.

Comment: @rasher I forgot about that case; thanks!

Comment: No worries - it popped up in a check when I was benching various methods - I thought "WTF? no way MW's was wrong...". An unimaginably small probability that the test lists generated would contain such a list... time go to Monte Carlo and hit the tables ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Length /@ Select[Table[Take[lst, i], {i, Length[lst]}], Last[#] == Min[#] &]
```

(* 
{1,4,7}
*)