# The minima for a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long table of data (the number of rows 795,000) and I need to create a code in Mathematica that can calculate the minimum value for every 5000 rows and then I need to know the positions of these minima.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you need something like [this (76121)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76121/10397), i.e the sequential running minima? Or must it be by chunks?

Answer (score 3):

First, you split yuor big data into chunks of size 5000 rows you will have a matrix like this:

```
 chunkOfMatrix = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 5000}, {j, 1, 100}];
```

Then applying this  will give the Min and its position in each row:

```
{Min[#], Position[#, Min[#]]} & /@ chunkOfMatrix
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please can you explain more if my data is already as a matrix and its name is data, how can I use your command?

Comment: Welcome, so if your data is smth. like this : `data = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 150000}, {j, 1, 100}];` and you can partition this data into chunks of 5000 rows using Partition function:  `dataChunks = Partition[data, 5000];` and then use the code above for every chunk. For example for the first one would be `{Min[#], Position[#, Min[#]]} & /@ dataChunks[[1]]`. Did I get you right?

Comment: I tried your way, but I didn't get what I need. For more details my data is below

Comment: Sorry, my data is huge!

Comment: Ohh, in this way you maybe need to write your data to a file and read it by portions.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a running  minima, then the answer already exists [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76131/10397). If you need it by chunks, then

Some data as an example (you use your own)

```
data = RandomReal[1, 795000];
```

The function

```
MinPositionAndValueByChunks[data_List, chunks_Integer] := MapIndexed[
  {First@FirstPosition[#1, Min[#1]] + chunks (First[#2] - 1), 
    Min[#1]} &,
  Partition[data, chunks]
  ]
```

Example

```
Short@MinPositionAndValueByChunks[data, 5000]
```

> ```
> {{2042,0.0000435445},{6324,0.000265437},<<155>>,{787796,0.000635954},{793848,0.000139004}}
> ```

Comment: I tried to use your command, but my data has specific numbers. It is the result of another code that computes the differential cross section, so do you think I can use RandomReal.? I should get stability minima.

Comment: @Ghady You must be kidding, the random data I offer is just for testing. For the benefit of the people that do not have access to your data, as you did not share it.